# Android Call Log data between two dates and Total duration of calls from same number.

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, duration, android-cursor, calllog

want to get the call log history by today, yesterday, last seven days and last 30days along with that i want to show the total duration of incoming and outgoing calls of that particular number.

suppose **abc** has 3 outgoing and 1 incoming calls. i should get the total duration of those calls.

just let me know if we can get duration and calls log by cursor **GroupBy** or **ORDER BY** clause rather than looping and adding duration. Just give me rough structure for better solution and can work effectively .

```
         String[] whereValue=null;
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String currentDate = String.valueOf(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
        switch (period) {
            case DAY:
                whereValue  = new String[]{getTimeFrom(period),currentDate};
                break;
            case YESTERDAY:
                whereValue  = new String[]{getTimeFrom(period),currentDate};
                break;
            case WEEK:
                whereValue  = new String[]{getTimeFrom(period),currentDate};

                break;
            case MONTH:
                    whereValue  = new String[]{getTimeFrom(period),currentDate};
                break;
            default:
                Log.d(Utils.LOG_TAG, "Error:");
        }
        String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
        Uri callUri = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");

        Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(callUri, null, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE+" BETWEEN ? AND ?", whereValue, strOrder);

   String callNumber = cur.getString(cur
                    .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));

            String callName = cur
                    .getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));
      String callType = cur.getString(cur
                    .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE));
            String dir = null;
            int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
            switch (dircode) {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    break;

            }
            String duration = cur.getString(cur
                    .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION));
```

the above code is even not working for getting call log between fromdate to till date. any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have managed to get the call log between two dates.  You can get call log of today, yesterday, last seven days, last 30days. as well duration of calls (calls from same number multiple times also)

you should pass *selection* as
 **android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " BETWEEN ? AND ?"** 
and

*selectionArgs*

**whereValue = new String[]{String.valueOf(calendar1.getTimeInMillis()),String.valueOf(calendar.getTimeInMillis());};**

```
  Map<String, StatEntry> callLogMap1 = new HashMap<>();
            callLogMap1.clear();

            String strOrder1 = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC limit 500";

            Uri callUri = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
            Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " BETWEEN ? AND ?", whereValue,
                    strOrder1);


            if (cur != null) {
                try {
                    while (cur.moveToNext()) {

                        String callNumber = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
                        //    String callDate = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE));
                        int duration = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION));

                        String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));

                        StatEntry StatEntry1 = null;

                        int id = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls._ID));

                        int type = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE));

                        if (callNumber != null & duration > 0 && (type == 1 || type == 2)) {

                            int n = callNumber.length();
                            String lastDigits;
String number = callNumber.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("+"), ""); //replacing the plus
    //am just checking last 5digitis and saving to map so that we can get same //number duration
                            if (n >= 5) {

                                try {

                                    lastDigits = String.valueOf(Long.parseLong(number) % 100000);
                                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    lastDigits = callNumber;
                                }
                            } else {
                                lastDigits = callNumber;
                            }

                            if (callLogMap1.containsKey(lastDigits)) {
                                StatEntry1 = callLogMap1.get(callNumber);

                                    StatEntry1.setTitle(callNumber);
                                StatEntry1.Duration += duration;


                            } else {
                                StatEntry1 = new StatEntry();

                  StatEntry1.setTitle(callNumber);

      StatEntry1.Duration += duration;
                           }


                    StatEntry1.setTime((StatEntry1.Duration) / 60);


                            callLogMap1.put(callNumber, StatEntry1);


                        }
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(

                    );
                } finally {
                    cur.close();
                }
            }
```

atlast passing hashmap data to arraylist.

```
ArrayList<StatEntry> callLogList1 = new ArrayList<>(callLogMap1.size());

        if (callLogMap1.size() > 0) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, StatEntry> entry : callLogMap1.entrySet()) {
                callLogList1.add(entry.getValue());


            }
        }
```

hope this will be helpful for viewers.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to get the call log between two dates and also you can get the duration of the calls.Try this method..

```
public class CallLogActivity extends Activity {


TextView textView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_call_log);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textCallBetween);
    textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   // listcallLog = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.calllogItems);

    getCalldetails();


}

public void getCalldetails() {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

    String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";

    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();


    calender.set(2016, calender.NOVEMBER, 18);
    String fromDate = String.valueOf(calender.getTimeInMillis());

    calender.set(2016, calender.NOVEMBER, 20);
    String toDate = String.valueOf(calender.getTimeInMillis());

    String[] whereValue = {fromDate,toDate};


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " BETWEEN ? AND ?", whereValue, strOrder);

//   Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE, new String[]{" BETWEEN ? AND ?"}, strOrder);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);

    stringBuffer.append("Call Log :");

    while (managedCursor.moveToNext())
    {
        String phoneNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
        String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
        String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm");
        String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(Long
                .parseLong(callDate)));
      //  Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);



        String dir = null;

        int dirCode = Integer.parseInt(callType);



        switch (dirCode)
        {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE :
                dir = "OUTGOING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                dir = "INCOMMING";
                break;
            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                dir = "MISSED CALL";
                break;

        }

        stringBuffer.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phoneNumber + "\nCall Type:--- "
                + dir + "\nCall Date:---"
                + dateString + "\nCall Duration:---" + callDuration);
        stringBuffer.append("\n--------------------------");

    }

    textView.setText(stringBuffer);
    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

}